# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n -a_{n-1}|<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n -a_{n-1}|<\infty$, then the series
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, is convergent
>
> 1. nowhere on $\mathbb{R}$;
> 2. everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$;
> 3. on some set containing $(-1,1)$
> 4. only on $(-1,1)$
>
> Which one is true?

Here is what I have tried so far:

Consider $x=1$. Let ${a_n}={1/n}$. The power series becomes series $\sum 1/n$ which is divergent. Also $a_n$ satisfies the above condition.

Comment: The answer is 3) but you have to show some effort before you can expect more details.

Comment: sir I have tried but  i didn't get any way to approach

Comment: @Arindambasak If you have tried a thing or two, why not include what you have tried in your question post? It doesn't matter that it didn't lead to a solution (that's most of the reason for this site to exist, after all). It will help us assess what you know and how to solve this in a way you will understand.

Comment: Have you tried producing a counter example to 1)?

Comment: Studying the partial sum and applying the triangle inequality would give you some extra information.

Comment: at x=1 , and let {a_n}={1/n} the power series becomes series 1/n which is divergent. and also a_n satisfies the above condition

Comment: When $a_n=1/n$ the power series becomes $\sum x^n/n$ which converges for some $x$.

Comment: so how do you conclude option 3?

Answer (score 1):

By the assumptions, the power series (constructed formally as)
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n=(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-a_{n-1})x^n$$ has a radius of convergence of at least $1$.